# Call javascript function from javaFX after delay

Tags: javascript, javafx, timeout, leaflet, sleep

im trying to add markers to a map with Leaflet.

I'm currently trying to add a new marker after x seconds but all i've tried didn't work.

My problem: 
I want to add 5 marker, each after 1 second. But all that's happening is that after 5x1 seconds all marker appear on my map.

I think the problem ist, that i am trying to call my addMarker() function (which is javaScript) from my javaFX method. But i've also tried to fut a sleep() call in my JavaScript funtion, still didn't work.

I've already tried Thread.sleep(x) (which isn't even a good solution), timeout() and timeline(), nothing worked though.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Asiemie

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for people to be able to help you.

Comment: Also the major work would most likely better be done from java code.